# Optimization and speed enhancement of function using JAX

Tags: python, optimization, jax

The code performs Gaussian blurring on the image `intensityRefracted2DF` using a Gaussian kernel centered at each pixel. The Gaussian kernel is determined by the values in the `darkField` array, where each value represents the standard deviation (sigma) of the Gaussian kernel to create for the corresponding pixel.

The process proceeds as follows:

1. The code generates two random arrays: `intensityRefracted2DF` and `darkField`.
2. Next, for each pixel in the `intensityRefracted2DF` image, the code checks if both the pixel value and the corresponding value in `darkField` are nonzero.
3. If they are nonzero, the code creates a Gaussian kernel centered at the pixel, with the standard deviation determined by the value in `darkField`.
4. The Gaussian kernel is then multiplied by the pixel value in `intensityRefracted2DF`.
5. The resulting value is added to the `intensityRefracted3` image, centered at the original pixel, effectively blurring the image.
6. The process is repeated for each pixel in `intensityRefracted2DF`, and in the end, `intensityRefracted3` contains the resulting blurred image.

In summary, the code performs Gaussian blurring on the `intensityRefracted2DF` image, where the standard deviation of the Gaussian kernel applied to each pixel is determined by the `darkField` array. The result is stored in the `intensityRefracted3` array, representing the resulting blurred image.

[image: intensityRefracted2DF]
[image: intensityRefracted3]

there is the original code:

```
intensityRefracted2DF = np.random.rand(10,10)
intensityRefracted3 = np.zeros((10, 10))
darkField = np.random.rand(10, 10)
intensityRefracted3=np.pad(intensityRefracted3, 10, mode='constant')
darkField=np.pad(darkField, 10, mode='constant')
intensityRefracted2DF=np.pad(intensityRefracted2DF, 10, mode='constant')


def darkFieldLoop0(margin2, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField, Nx, Ny):
    """
    Perform dark field microscopy calculations.

    Args:
        margin2 (int): Margin size.
        intensityRefracted2DF (2D numpy array): Intensity refracted after propagation.
        intensityRefracted3 (2D numpy array): Intensity refracted after applying dark field.
        darkField (2D numpy array): Dark field values.
        Nx (int): Width of intensityRefracted2DF and intensityRefracted3.
        Ny (int): Height of intensityRefracted2DF and intensityRefracted3.

    Returns:
        intensityRefracted3 (2D numpy array): Updated intensity refracted after applying dark         field.
    """

    print(intensityRefracted3.shape)
    for i in range(10, Nx + 10):
        for j in range(10, Ny + 10):
            if intensityRefracted2DF[i, j] != 0:
                if darkField[i, j] != 0:
                    # print('la',i)
                    currDF = darkField[i, j]
                    patch = gaussian_shape1(currDF)
                    size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2
                    patch = patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
                
                    intensityRefracted3[i - size2:i + size2 + 1, j - size2:j + size2 + 1] += patch
                else:
                    intensityRefracted3[i, j] += intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
    return intensityRefracted3


def gaussian_shape1(sigma):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.

    Args:
        sigma (float): Standard deviation of the Gaussian shape.

    Returns:
        exponent (2D numpy array): Gaussian shape.
    """
    dim = int(2 * np.ceil(3 * sigma) + 1)
    x = np.arange(0, dim) - np.floor(dim / 2)
    exponent = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = exponent.reshape((-1, 1)) * exponent.reshape((1, -1))
    exponent /= np.sum(exponent)
    # plt.imshow(exponent)
    # plt.show()
    return exponent


b = darkFieldLoop0(0, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField, 10, 10)

plt.imshow(b)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(intensityRefracted2DF)
plt.show()
```

I have rewritten the code to make it compatible with JAX by removing the loops and optimizing it. Here's what I attempted to achieve.

```
intensityRefracted2DF = np.random.rand(10,10)
intensityRefracted3 = np.zeros((10, 10))
darkField = np.random.rand(10, 10)
intensityRefracted3=np.pad(intensityRefracted3, 10, mode='constant')
darkField=np.pad(darkField, 10, mode='constant')
intensityRefracted2DF=np.pad(intensityRefracted2DF, 10, mode='constant')

@jax.jit
def apply_dark_field(i, j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    currDF_ij=darkField[i,j]
    patch = gaussian_shape(currDF_ij,10)
    size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2
    patch = patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]


    # intensityRefracted3 = intensityRefracted3.at[i - size2:i + size2 + 1, j - size2:j + size2 + 1].add(patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j])
    start_indices = (i - size2, j - size2)
    update = jax.lax.dynamic_slice(intensityRefracted3, start_indices, patch.shape)
    update += patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
    intensityRefracted3 = jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice(
        intensityRefracted3, update,  start_indices)
    
    # intensityRefracted3 = jax.ops.index_add(intensityRefracted3, (i, j), intensityRefracted2DF[i, j] * (darkField[i, j] == 0))
    return intensityRefracted3

@partial(jax.jit,static_argnums=(1,))
def gaussian_shape(sigma, size):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.

    Args:
        sigma (float or 2D numpy array): Standard deviation(s) of the Gaussian shape.
        size (int): Size of the Gaussian shape.

    Returns:
        exponent (2D numpy array): Gaussian shape.
    """

    x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor(size / 2)
    exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = jnp.outer(exponent, exponent)
    exponent /= jnp.sum(exponent)
    return exponent

@jax.jit
def darkFieldLoop(intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    currDF = jnp.zeros_like(intensityRefracted3)
    currDF = jnp.where(intensityRefracted2DF!=0,darkField,0)

    i = jnp.nonzero(currDF,size=currDF.shape[0])
    indices_i=i[0]
    indices_j=i[1]

    intensityRefracted3 = jnp.zeros_like(intensityRefracted3)

    intensityRefracted3 = jax.vmap(apply_dark_field, in_axes=(0, 0, None, None, None))(indices_i, indices_j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField)

    return intensityRefracted3
```

My problem is that the obtained result is not the same. Initially, when I use the vmap function, I get a 3D array of shape (30, 30, 30), whereas I would like to obtain only a 2D array (30, 30) as in the original code.I am having trouble understanding which function to use and how to iterate without encountering issues with tracers, etc.

Comment: The two implementations are not efficient. Gaussian kernels can be implemented far more efficiently when the radius is big. The first optimization to do is to use a [separable filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter). Then, the second one is to use an FFT-based convolution for relatively large radius. For small ones, the loop order need to be changed so the convolution is done item per item. In fact, SIMD instructions can be used to do that more efficiently. Regarding the use-case, 32-bit floats might be enough. Then GPUs can speed this up even further (for large arrays).

Comment: no idea how about performance compared to `jax`, but if you use `numba` package you probably won't have to change much of the code, it should be easier to write and read.

Comment: If you plan to use FFT as Jerome suggested, remember about problems at boundaries. Imagine infinite plane of tiles, each being your image, next to each other. FFT transforms such an infinite plane, not a single image. If there are some large differences on the opposites of the image, there will be some discontnuity artifacts in the results. There are tricks to avoid it, but if performance is not **that** important, I would avoid doing FFT in the first place.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I’ve answer you in the next post

Comment: @dankal444 I’ve answer you also in the next post

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jérôme, I first implemented the separability of the filters for creating the Gaussian. Since the Gaussian is separable, it simplifies things greatly. Here is the modified part:

```
# Définition de la fonction avec le filtre gaussien séparable
def gaussian_filter_1d(sigma, size):
    x = np.arange(0, size) - (size - 1) / 2
    exponent = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = exponent * exponent[:,np.newaxis]
    return exponent / np.sum(exponent)
```

However, I would like more explanation regarding the use of FFT, please. I know that convolution in the Fourier domain is equivalent to simple multiplication in the real domain, and vice versa. Should I apply this for creating the Gaussian?

Thank you dankal444. Apologies for not mentioning it earlier, but I'm already using Numba for optimization. However, I want to switch the code to the GPU, and for that, I would like to use JAX. From your help, if I understood correctly, it seems that applying zero-padding will help to deal with the artifacts?

Comment: Depends on the images you have. To avoid artifacts you can do windowing (making "fade out" to zero at boundaries) or mirroring of the image (adding mirrored versions of the image around it, maybe windowing it too). I would try mirroring, but first try doing nothing and take a look if artifacts are large enough to worry about.

Comment: If you really want to use FFTs, then I strongly advise you to use existing function for that like [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html). Note the function has a `mode` parameter for the boundary conditions. Note that 2D FFTs are generally implemented by applying 1D FFTs, then transposing the array and applying 1D FFTs on the same axis before re-transposing the array (optional regarding the target processing). This is somehow an optimization similar to separable filter except it works for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach I used in optimizing my code using Jax. I made the choice not to use the FFT Convolution function yet. Indeed, at first, I tried to use it, perhaps I did it incorrectly, but it was slower in terms of execution time. Regarding the code, here is the approach I have taken, and I would like to optimize it even further. Maybe you have some ideas?

```
@partial(jax.jit,static_argnums=(1,))
def gaussian_shape(sigma, size):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.

    Args:
        sigma (float or 2D numpy array): Standard deviation(s) of the Gaussian shape.
        size (int): Size of the Gaussian shape.

    Returns:
        exponent (2D numpy array): Gaussian shape.
    """

    x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor((size-1) / 2)
    exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = exponent * exponent[:,np.newaxis]
    return exponent / jnp.sum(exponent)




@jax.jit
def apply_dark_field(i, j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    patch = gaussian_shape(darkField[i,j],8)
    size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2

    start_indices = (i - size2, j - size2)
    update = jax.lax.dynamic_slice(intensityRefracted3, start_indices, patch.shape)
    patch = patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
    update += patch
    intensityRefracted3 = jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice(
        intensityRefracted3, update,  start_indices)
    
    return intensityRefracted3


@jax.jit
def darkFieldLoop(intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    currDF = jnp.zeros_like(intensityRefracted3)
    currDF = jnp.where(jnp.logical_and(intensityRefracted2DF!=0,darkField!=0),darkField,0)

    i = jnp.nonzero(currDF,size=101)
    indices_i=i[0]
    indices_j=i[1]
    darkField = darkField.at[indices_i[-1],indices_j[-1]].set(1)

    intensityRefracted3= jax.vmap(apply_dark_field, in_axes=(0, 0, None, None, None))(indices_i, indices_j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField)

    return intensityRefracted3


intensityRefracted3=darkFieldLoop(intensityRefracted2DF,intensityRefracted3,darkField)

plt.imshow(intensityRefracted3[-1,::,::])
plt.title('Matrice of intensity after blurring')
plt.show()
```